# How to Print logs on Command Line while running the application (.exe) from command line using set path property in Qt Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmd

I am using Qt 5.5.1 windows/Linux. I have a .pro file in my project folder. Inside that project folder, Qt IDE creates a .exe application file after building my project. Now as I go inside the debug folder from Command Line, I do

```
 set path="C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5.1\mingw48_32\bin"
```

Then, I try :

```
START /WAIT myapplication.exe
```

In my project, I am using statements such as:

```
QDebug()<<"My logs are not getting displayed";
printf("My logs are not getting displayed");
system("Please do something");
```

Nothing is getting displayed on my running command line. Please help me regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

This line is not correct.

```
QDebug()<<"My logs are not getting displayed";
```

This should works:

```
qDebug()<<"My logs are not getting displayed";
```

And this should works but don't use it in few threads at same time:

```
QTextStream(stdout)<<"My logs are not getting displayed";
```

Comment: Well, printf() and std::cout are also fine :)

Comment: Direct printing to console is also not thread save.

In result of concurrent stdout streaming you can get output like this:


    "Hello woWhatsrld up" instead of "Hello world Whats up".

QDebug, QWarning etc made to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right - of course these calls are not thread safe : I wanted to point out the simplest ways for console output.

Comment: Hey, I tried using the above statements. Still no luck. (In my main function). Also,my application is not a console application. I am using GUI based QApplication object and using exec() function to launch the GUI.

Comment: Also, if I try running the same .run file using Linux terminal ,qDebug() works perfectly. And if I run the same .exe in Windows using Qt IDE, I can see qDebug() output in the application output window of IDE. Only problem is qDebug() or any of the above statements are not printing logs on windows command Line.